# ASP.NET ASMX Web Service

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis-7, asmx

I have a website published in IIS 7.0 which works perfectly. I just wanted to add a few more functions that I have created. When I replaced the IIS files with the new version, it didn't update the files and still showed the old services. The new services should be in place at the server but this is not working.

I used the same procedure when I published but I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: did you try to iisreset, just in case ?

Comment: website or webservice?? IIS files? You mean the files in the folder that IIS is pointing to for the site/service? How are you building/deploying the site. Does it work when you debug from visual studio? Far too little info in this question for meaningful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Stop your service, and restart. I also suggest that you create a custom Application Pool in IIS for your application as it will have it's own disposal area and not interfere with any other application.

You can also try to stop the service, delete the contents of the folder, and then upload your republished code and restart the application.

Comment: Actually it's kept in IIS Default Website directory and I did stop and restart it to check but no difference. The service locally works fine but not on IIS. It looks I need to compile it over IIS somehow but not sure how.

Comment: I would suggest that you put it in it's own application and not in the default website. Give it it's own App Pool, and make sure that the Application is configured to the correct .NET framework. If you've written it in .NET 4 and you have it set to .NET 2 then probably won't have a working application.

Comment: See this is the same application which I had published to IIS few months before and it was working but now when I updated the files there, they are no more working.